# Crystal Report for Average Tickets revived by hour per month

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, average

I need to pull a report that show the avg tickets we receive per hour for a month.

So far I've been able to come up with:

```
 SELECT "TASKS"."WO_NUM", "TASKS"."TASK", "TASKS"."COMPLETED", "TASKS"."OPENDATE", 
"TASKS"."REQUEST", "TASKS"."RESPONS"
     FROM   "TRACKIT9_DATA"."dbo"."TASKS" "TASKS"
     WHERE  ("TASKS"."OPENDATE">={ts '2015-09-01 00:00:00'} AND
 "TASKS"."OPENDATE"<{ts '2015-09-04 00:00:00'})
```

However this only show the number of ticket we received each hour per day and the report is a mess if I ask for a full months worth of data.

How would I go about asking Crystal Reports to Pull the data then Group it by Hour then give me an average?

Comment: you want to group by the month part of the openDate, then determine the average by dividing the number of tasks by the number of hours in that month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in crystal report.

Group by month then create a formula and write as

```
Hour(database date field)
```

Use this to group as a second group after month, now try to manipulate the data